Accurate computation of the inverse of the scaled complementary error function using standard C
This is a self-answered question, as encouraged on Stackoverflow for sharing knowledge. As such, it is a follow-on to my previous self-answered question about the accurate computation of the exponentially scaled error function erfcx(x) := exp(x²) · erfc(x).
I recently came across multiple papers [1],[2],[3] that make use of the inverse of the scaled complementary error function, erfcxinv(). It seems to have particular utility in chromatography for the computation of the mode (the location of a peak's maximum) when the exponentially modified Gaussian distribution is used to model chromatographic peaks.
How can the inverse of the scaled complementary error function be computed accurately and with reasonable efficiency using the standard C math library?
By accurate I mean that the maximum error of function results shall not exceed 4 ulps. This is identical to the error bound that applies to the LA profile of the Intel math library, and I have found it to be a reasonable and useful error bound for non-trivial transcendental functions in practical use. Support for IEEE-754 (2008) binary floating-point arithmetic and functionally-correct support for fused multiply-add (FMA) operations accessible via the fma() standard library function can be assumed.

[1] Vlad-Stefan Raducanu, et al., "Two chromatographic schemes for protein purification involving the biotin/avidin interaction under native conditions." Journal of Chromatography A, Jun. 2020, 1621:461051.
[2] Muhammad Tehseen, et al., "Proliferating cell nuclear antigen-agarose column: A tag-free and tag-dependent tool for protein purification affinity chromatography." Journal of Chromatography A, Sep. 2019, 1602:341-349
[3] K. van Dam, B. van Eijk, and J.J.M. Steijger, "Reconstructing the cosmic ray energy spectrum with HiSPARC." Astroparticle Physics, Vol. 143, Oct. 2022, 102747

Like all error function variants, the scaled complementary error function can be inverted efficiently with cubically-convergent Halley iterations. Except for the vicinity of unity, the asymptotic approximations -√(log (x / 2)) for x → ∞, and 1/√(π·x) for x → 0 are suitable as initial guesses, and for x very small and very large in magnitude the asymptotic approximations themselves deliver accurate results. For the vicinity of unity a low-order polynomial approximation can be used as the starting guess.
Using these initial guesses, one finds experimentally that three Halley iterations, and thus three evaluations of erfcx(), are sufficient to reach full double (mapped to IEEE 754 binary64) precision, with the exception of a narrow band about unity. For this region a rational minimax approximation was generated with the Remez algorithm.
The exemplary ISO-C99 implementation erfcxinv() below exhibited no errors larger than 3.6145 ulps in a test run with 1 billion random test vectors. While testing cannot prove error bounds, this makes it likely that a 4 ulp error bound is being maintained across the entire input domain.
#include <math.h>
double erfcx (double);

// In 1B tests: maximum errpr = 3.6145 ulps @ 1.7439789057636135
double erfcxinv (double a)
{
    const double c = 0.5641895835477562869481; // 1/sqrt(pi)
    double e, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x;

    // special cases
    if (isnan (a)) return a + a;
    if (a < 0) return INFINITY / INFINITY; // NaN

    // Halley iteration does not work well around unity: rational approximation
    if ((a > 19.0/32) && (a < 51.0/32)) {
        t = 1 - a;
        p =            -9.9577362854734097e-1;
        p = fma (p, t,  2.5714995288801855e+1);
        p = fma (p, t, -2.0689956608976641e+2);
        p = fma (p, t,  7.4307246888729856e+2);
        p = fma (p, t, -1.3434194015527373e+3);
        p = fma (p, t,  1.2287551470371382e+3);
        p = fma (p, t, -4.9782808803242131e+2);
        p = fma (p, t,  4.9533724768600912e+1);
        q =         t  -2.7622396967308187e+1;
        q = fma (q, t,  2.4716925574847096e+2);
        q = fma (q, t, -1.0276851232159131e+3);
        q = fma (q, t,  2.2643646204587053e+3);
        q = fma (q, t, -2.7339512610053207e+3);
        q = fma (q, t,  1.7120977945481272e+3);
        q = fma (q, t, -4.3537299985712372e+2);
        return fma (p / q, t, t);
    }

    // starting approximation for Halley iteration
    if (a > 2.75) {
        x = -sqrt (log (a / 2));
    } else if (a < 0.375) {
        x = c / a;
    } else {
        t = a - 1;
        x = fma (fma (-0.32374940733, t, 0.87922595958), t, -1.003428026) * t;
    }

    // early exit if starting approximation already sufficiently accurate 
    if ((a < 1.6455e-8) || (a > 0x1.0p51)) return x; 

    // Halley iterations
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        e = erfcx (x);
        q = fma (e, x, -c);
        r = 1 / q;
        s = 0.5 * r;
        t = (a - e) * s;    // -f(x) / f'(x)
        u = fma (e, s, x);  // f"(x) / 2f'(x)
        v = fma (t, u, 1);
        w = 1 / v;
        x = fma (t, w, x);
    }
    return x;
}

double erfcx (double x)
{
    double a, d, e, m, p, q, r, s, t;

    a = fmax (x, 0.0 - x); // NaN preserving absolute value computation

    /* Compute q = (a-4)/(a+4) accurately. [0,INF) -> [-1,1] */
    m = a - 4.0;
    p = a + 4.0;
    r = 1.0 / p;
    q = m * r;
    t = fma (q + 1.0, -4.0, a); 
    e = fma (q, -a, t); 
    q = fma (r, e, q); 

    /* Approximate (1+2*a)*exp(a*a)*erfc(a) as p(q)+1 for q in [-1,1] */
    s = q * q;
    p =             0x1.edcad78fc8044p-31;  //  8.9820305531190140e-10
    t =             0x1.b1548f14735d1p-30;  //  1.5764464777959401e-09
    p = fma (p, s, -0x1.a1ad2e6c4a7a8p-27); // -1.2155985739342269e-08
    t = fma (t, s, -0x1.1985b48f08574p-26); // -1.6386753783877791e-08
    p = fma (p, s,  0x1.c6a8093ac4f83p-24); //  1.0585794011876720e-07
    t = fma (t, s,  0x1.31c2b2b44b731p-24); //  7.1190423171700940e-08
    p = fma (p, s, -0x1.b87373facb29fp-21); // -8.2040389712752056e-07
    t = fma (t, s,  0x1.3fef1358803b7p-22); //  2.9796165315625938e-07
    p = fma (p, s,  0x1.7eec072bb0be3p-18); //  5.7059822144459833e-06
    t = fma (t, s, -0x1.78a680a741c4ap-17); // -1.1225056665965572e-05
    p = fma (p, s, -0x1.9951f39295cf4p-16); // -2.4397380523258482e-05
    t = fma (t, s,  0x1.3be1255ce180bp-13); //  1.5062307184282616e-04
    p = fma (p, s, -0x1.a1df71176b791p-13); // -1.9925728768782324e-04
    t = fma (t, s, -0x1.8d4aaa0099bc8p-11); // -7.5777369791018515e-04
    p = fma (p, s,  0x1.49c673066c831p-8);  //  5.0319701025945277e-03
    t = fma (t, s, -0x1.0962386ea02b7p-6);  // -1.6197733983519948e-02
    p = fma (p, s,  0x1.3079edf465cc3p-5);  //  3.7167515521269866e-02
    t = fma (t, s, -0x1.0fb06dfedc4ccp-4);  // -6.6330365820039094e-02
    p = fma (p, s,  0x1.7fee004e266dfp-4);  //  9.3732834999538536e-02
    t = fma (t, s, -0x1.9ddb23c3e14d2p-4);  // -1.0103906603588378e-01
    p = fma (p, s,  0x1.16ecefcfa4865p-4);  //  6.8097054254651804e-02
    t = fma (t, s,  0x1.f7f5df66fc349p-7);  //  1.5379652102610957e-02
    p = fma (p, q, t);
    p = fma (p, q, -0x1.1df1ad154a27fp-3);  // -1.3962111684056208e-01
    p = fma (p, q,  0x1.dd2c8b74febf6p-3);  //  2.3299511862555250e-01

    /* Divide (1+p) by (1+2*a) ==> exp(a*a)*erfc(a) */
    d = a + 0.5;
    r = 1.0 / d;
    r = r * 0.5;
    q = fma (p, r, r); // q = (p+1)/(1+2*a)
    t = q + q;
    e = (p - q) + fma (t, -a, 1.0); // residual: (p+1)-q*(1+2*a)
    r = fma (e, r, q);

    /* Handle argument of infinity */
    if (a > 0x1.fffffffffffffp1023) r = 0.0;

    /* Handle negative arguments: erfcx(x) = 2*exp(x*x) - erfcx(|x|) */
    if (x < 0.0) {
        s = x * x;
        d = fma (x, x, -s);
        e = exp (s);
        r = e - r;
        r = fma (e, d + d, r); 
        r = r + e;
        if (e > 0x1.fffffffffffffp1023) r = e; // avoid creating NaN
    }
    return r;
}


Minor: Why magic number approach with a > 0x1.fffffffffffffp1023 instead of a > DBL_MAX or isinf(a)?
